# Create table and insert two records SQL using python

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I'm trying to create a table on a `tempdb` database on a local server `KHBW001` using MSSQL. My code is:

```
import pyodbc

connection = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=KHBW001;'
                      'Database=tempdb;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.executemany(
    "CREATE TABLE tempdb.dbo.NewTestPyTable(Symbol varchar(15), Shares integer, Price double)")  # creates new table

cursor.executemany("""
                INSERT INTO tempdb.dbo.NewTestPyTable (Symbol, Shares, Price)
                VALUES
                [('ETH',55,199.55),
                ('KHC',66,33.5)]
                """)  # insert two records into new table

connection.commit()
```

I'm getting the error:

> "CREATE TABLE tempdb.dbo.NewTestPyTable(Symbol varchar(15), Shares
>   integer, Price double)")  # creates new table
>
> TypeError: function takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

I don't quite understand what I'm doing wrong. Please assist

Comment: you should be using `executemany` as opposed to `execute` --> https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor#executemanysql-params-with-fast_executemanyfalse-the-default

Comment: I tried that, didn't work @aws_apprentice

Comment: wrap your sql statement in 3 double quotes as opposed to three single ticks so that your string column can be properly formatted, also put your parameters in a list as per how the GH shows

Comment: I did that... now i'm getting the error ```TypeError: function takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)```

Comment: how about you update your post with what you have tried, because I nor any one else can see how you attempted this...

Comment: Done @aws_apprentice

Comment: the values you are inserting go outside the statement, they are the second parameter to executemany. please take a look at the link I posted if that is not clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out...

```
import pyodbc

connection = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=KHBW001;'
                      'Database=tempdb;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(
    "CREATE TABLE NewTestPyTable(Symbol varchar(15), Shares integer, Price integer)")  # creates new table
params = [('ETH', 55, 199),
          ('KHC', 66, 33)]
# insert two records into new table
cursor.executemany(
    "INSERT INTO tempdb.dbo.NewTestPyTable (Symbol, Shares, Price) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", params)

connection.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

i think first of all the problem is in table creation

here is the documentation how to create it correctly
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_table.asp

type of data in SQL
https://www.journaldev.com/16774/sql-data-types

further it seems to me
you also need to use the money type for the price.

that's how i would do:

```
    import pyodbc
connection = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=KHBW001;'
                      'Database=tempdb;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.executemany(
    "CREATE TABLE tempdb.dbo.NewTestPyTable(Symbol varchar(15), Shares int, Price money)")  # creates new table

cursor.executemany("""
                INSERT INTO tempdb.dbo.NewTestPyTable (Symbol, Shares, Price)
                VALUES
                ('ETH',55,199.55),
                ('KHC',66,33.5);
                """)  # insert two records into new table

connection.commit()
```